# Java/Json - How to add/pass an ApiKey in the HttpPost request header?

Tags: java, json, http-post, api-key, request-headers

I don't want to pass the apiKey using request.setEntity() method. I only want to pass it in the request header. Is it correct if I name the header as "Authorization"? Please correct me if what I'm doing is wrong.

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpPost request = new HttpPost(restAPIServiceURL);
request.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
request.addHeader("Accept","application/json");
request.addHeader("Authorization","apiKey=AIzaSyCXhu........");
request.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonString)); //I have other data to pass as Entity.

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
```

Is there any other better way to pass the apiKey in the request header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can use this

```
String API_KEY = "YOUR API KEY";
String basicAuth = "Basic"  + new String(Base64.encode(API_KEY.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));
request.addHeader("Authorization", basicAuth);
```

Comment: That's look great. Any chance I can use something similar like apiKey = "MyApiKey" ?

Comment: hi, can you show me how/where do I can use apiKey = "MyApiKey" ?

Comment: I've edited the answer. just set the variable API_KEY.